# Iphone, Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Does anyone know how to install cocos2d so it shows up in the new projects template window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there's a Project Template file included with the cocos2d distribution, you'll have to make one yourself which, sadly, I don't know how to do exactly (I could probably stumble my way through it, but that's not helpful to you...).

However, when you eventually do have your Project Template, you need to copy it into:
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Project Templates

This may be of help to you:

http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2009/01/xcode-template-for-cocos2d.html

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the template in this directory:

`/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Project Templates/Application/`

(via [Jeff Lamarche's iPhone Development blog](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/12/updated-opengl-es-xcode-project.html))

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there are no template projects.  It's however very simple to get cocos up and running with XCode.  Here's a great walkthrough [link](http://monoclestudios.com/cocos2d_whitepaper.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great tutorial for Cocos2D that's also got a template to get you started, from Keith Peters at Bit-101: http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=2115

Answer (score 0):

1-open cocos2d folder
2-open terminal window
3-type: sudo
4-and drag and drop file:install-templates.sh (cocos2d) folder and return

start xcode and new project